# nested for() loops && using the "i" count from the first loop in the second so i loops just once using the value?

Tags: java, math, for-loop, helper, factorial

i am trying to not import the math class to use but i am still trying to estimate the constant  "e". it is said e= 1+(1/1!)+(1/2!)+(1/3!)+(1/4!)+(1/5!)+.....

these are what i have int at the top

> ```
> String userInput;
> int uIp; // this converts the string into int type 
> double e = 2;
> ```

then i ask some questions then i check to see not zero to exit and non negative to continue

> ```
> While(uIp >0){
>   final int endTheLoop = 15;
>   int factorialNumber = 1;
>   double e2TheUserInput=0;
>
>   for(int i = 2; i < endTheLoop; i++){
>     for(int j = 1; j < i; j++){  
>       factorialNumber = ((i - 1) * factorialNumber);
>     }
>     e = (1/factorialNumber) + e;
>     e2TheUserInput = Math.pow(e,uIp);
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: and your problem is??? I don't get the question here... Some explanation could help us all out! :)

Comment: What is your problem? (A hint though, dividing an int by an int results in an int so 1 / factorialNumber will give 1 or 0).

Comment: And you really aren't going to want that `while(uIp > 0)` - You should have a better way to start/end infinite loops.  And what's up with that factorial number calculation?  It's **NOT** generating the results you want (Hint: you don't need that second nested loop).  Also, look into recursive functionality, and why a simple naive translation isn't the best option.  Splitting this off into it's own routines will help here, especially in separating it from your input.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing integer division(but e is a double right?):

```
e = (1/factorialNumber) + e;
```

Correct that to:

```
e = (1.0/(double)factorialNumber) + e;
```

It was counting all the loops, but changes are zero according to the integer division. :)

e= 2+(0)+(0)+(0)+(0)+.....

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your code is trying to do but if you want to compute exp(x) this is how I would do it.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    for (int i = -4; i <= 4; i++)
        System.out.println(i + ": " + exp(i) + " cf " + Math.exp(i));
}

private static double exp(double d) {
    if (d < 0)
        return 1 / exp(-d);
    double e = 1, term = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 20 || term > e * 1e-16; i++) {
        term *= d / i;
        e += term;
    }
    return e;
}
```

---

For large exponents, it more efficient to evaluate the integral powers without using a taylor series.

```
public static final double E = 2.7182818284590452354;

private static double exp(double d) {
    if (d < 0)
        return 1 / exp(-d);
    long num = (long) d;
    double numE = 1;
    double mult = E;
    while (num > 0) {
        if ((num & 1) != 0)
            numE *= mult;
        num >>>= 1;
        mult *= mult;
    }
    double fract = d - (long) d;
    double fractE = 1, term = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
        term *= fract / i;
        fractE += term;
    }
    return numE * fractE;
}
```